# Apktool build fails due to Translation error

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, apktool

I took an APK file decompiled it using Apktool and made a few changes then I tried to recompiled it and I got this error.

```
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_needs_enabling_title' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_needs_installation_title' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_needs_update_title' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_requested_by_msg' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
aapt: warning: string 'auth_client_using_bad_version_title' has no default translation in C:\Users\Dell\android-sdks\platform-tools\MageSimi\SimiCart_com.magestore.simicart_2.0_5\res; found: af am ar be bg ca cs da de el en_GB en_IN es es_US et_EE fa fi fr fr_CA hi hr hu hy_AM in it iw ja ka_GE km_KH ko lo_LA lt lv mn_MN ms_MY nb nl pl pt pt_BR pt_PT ro ru sk sl sr sv sw th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW zu
```

I went to my resource file there are already translations available.
How to fix this error. Please Help I am on a tight deadline.
Thank You very much in Advance

Comment: The question is unreadable, you didn't specify what you were doing. Not to mention the only thing I see is warnings, no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that there is a `<string ...>...</string>` record in the file ' C:...\\res\values\strings.xml' file. You should be able to open this file using your favourite XML editor using the Windows Explorer or if you use by clicking on the strings.xml file which is not marked with a flag and has no parantheses right to its name. In the following screenshot the file is highlighted:

[image: default strings.xml in AndroidStudio]

In this XML file you have to add the string records for the resources `auth_client_needs_installation_title`, `auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg`, `auth_client_needs_update_title`, `auth_client_requested_by_msg` and `auth_client_using_bad_version_title`

Answer (score 3):

If you are migrating a ADT project to the new Android Studio, as Lukas mentioned the strings.xml in your res folder needs the following additional strings defined.

```
<string name="auth_client_needs_enabling_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_needs_installation_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_needs_update_title"></string>
<string name="auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg"></string>
<string name="auth_client_requested_by_msg"></string>
<string name="auth_client_using_bad_version_title"></string>
```

If you resource folder doesn't appear, right click the module and select "Open Module Settings" then find the module then select your resource folder (my was named res) and above in the "Mark as:" select Resources.